# After installation of OPENCV, Spyder fails to run in the latest Anaconda Python

Tags: python, opencv, spyder, anaconda3, qtpy

I installed the latest Anaconda Python 2023-09, in Windows 10 **as a new and clean installation**. It runs Spyder normally.
After installing OPENCV using the command "conda install conda-forge::opencv", next, Spyder is unable to work, and show me the message.
[image]

I tried to solve it using other suggestions in this forum, but without any success.
When I enter in the "anaconda promtp" and **import cv2**, the results is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

Can you experienced it or can I report it as a bug?

Nota:
I have win10, fully updated, and the NVIDIA driver also fully updated.

Comment: `No module named 'cv'` means you made a typo. the import is called `cv2` -- use official `opencv-python` package or its siblings. don't use condaforge. if you do, you'll have to talk to them about support and issues. as it stands, you don't even know *where* to report this issue. I don't see which package did what here, or what versions are involved.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, so what source of installation can I use istead of condaforge? Thanks.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/